# Undefined index: isset() will not return true

Tags: php, oop

Could someone please point me in the right direction. Im a working through tutorials in php but I cannot seem to get the following to return true for isset();. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 
class Config{
    public static function get($path = null){

        if($path){
            $config= $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('/',$path);

            print_r($path);
            foreach($path as $bit){
                if(isset($config[$bit])){
                    $config = $config[$bit];
                    echo 'set';

                }
                else{
                    echo 'unset';
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return $config;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Yes but everything seems to be fine. Im wondering would it have anything to do with old tutorials

Comment: Im very new to php so apologies if im wrong. But i have the global variable config set up in init.php and this is simply checking if those values have been set?

Comment: What are you passing as `$path`? Are you sure it uses forward slashes? What's in `$GLOBALS['config']`?

Comment: $GLOBALS['config'] its an array of arrays

Comment: Stores stores 3 arrays for mysql, remember and sessions

Comment: path in is 'mysql/host'